# WAP551 connected to WS-C2960X-24TD-L does not turn on, no PoE?

Tags: access-point, power-over-ethernet, cisco-2960

I just set up a new WS-C2960X-24TD-L, and I can access the switch via Network Assistant without any issues. However, when I plug in the WAP directly to the switch with the included cable, it seems to get no power, and nothing lights up.

I am fairly new to the Cisco switches and WAPs. Is there something I need to do to get PoE working so that the WAP will turn on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That particular switch model, WS-C2960X-24TD-L, doesn't have PoE.

[Cisco Catalyst 2960-X Series Switches Data Sheet](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/catalyst-2960-x-series-switches/data_sheet_c78-728232.html)

[image]

You will either need a switch which has PoE, or you will need an inline PoE adapter.

Comment: Thanks, lesson learned :) I guess I will get the adapter, I guess another name for what I need to get is PoE injector for anyone else with this issue.